# Pagination with oauth azure data factory

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-data-factory

Inside Azure data factory i make a call to microsoft graph through a REST copy activity utilizing rest to get an access token to the service. The Graph api returns max 200 results, and therefore i am interested in using the pagination rules that can be created in the source. In post man i can see that my response structure is

```
{
   "@odata.context" : <some context>,
   "@odata.nextLink" : <the link to next page>
   "value" : [<the response data on current page>]
}
```

I have read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#pagination-support) that i set the pagination rules by adding the key

```
AbsoluteUrl
```

and then the path to the next page given in the response as the value.
How do i tell azure data factory how to find this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your repsonse is a json structure the value of

```
AbsoluteUrl
```

should be

```
$['@odata.nextLink']
```

Comment: Is this Copy Activity added to Until activity?

Comment: @bjnr It has been a long time since i did this, but as i recall the `AbsoluteUrl` field is something you can set in the copy activity.

Comment: I set AbsoluteUrl , but it copies only first 1000 records and I don't understand why the next records are not copied. Maybe should I put this in an Until activity?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not how i did it. If your post request returns something like `"@odata.nextLink" : <the link to next page>` put that into your `AbsoluteUrl`. The copy activity should automatically go to the next page.

Edit:
this can also be seen in the link to the documentation that is in my original question

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this comment here so people know exactly what is missing from these previous answers. You need to have the **dynamic content** set as $['@odata.nextLink'] for the **AbsoluteUrl** and also you need to have the sink in copy data to have the **"File Pattern"** to be **"Array of Objects"**. That's what worked for me, I think you can use Set of Objects too, but I had it set to Array of objects and I was able to get subsequent pages.